# UaExpert - UA.NET Standard

Tags: opc, opc-ua

Can anybody explain to me the use of `UaExpert` and `UA.NET Standard`? I'm an opc ua beginner, and I would like to understand these two terms.

What I found:

- `UaExpert` is an OPC UA Client
- `UA.NET Standard` is an OPC UA implementation

And what is the meaning of the term OPC UA Stack?

Comment: yes! that's right UaExpert is a client, developers normally use to test their Opc Ua server with this Application as UI is pretty good of this Client(Unified Automation have done this very well),   Talking about UA.NET Standard it's an open-source project which gives a way to use the OPC UA protocol, so if you say what is OPC UA Stack? then it's just a standardization and UA.NET Standard is a library that implements this standardization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UaExpert and UA.NET Standard are both related to the OPC UA Protocol (Open Platform Communications - Unified Architecture).

OPC UA itself is a definition for data exchange acting as a platform independent, service oriented architecture. It is standardized under the IEC 62541 mainly driven by the OPC Foundation. The specification itself is freely available (after registration) on the OPC Foundation's webpage:  [OPC UA Specification](https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture).

**UaExpert:**

UaExpert is a commercial OPC UA Client developed by Unified Automation and available for free after registration: [UaExpert](https://www.unified-automation.com/products/development-tools/uaexpert.html)

This application is mainly used to connect to an existing OPC UA Server to browse its data, also called address space. UaExpert's main functionality is to read and write data to a server, call methods, and interact with the nodes within the address space. You can also see it as a debugging interface for an OPC UA Server. In production systems you normally would implement your own OPC UA Client which controls an OPC UA Server automatically.

**UA.NET Standard**

UA.NET Standard is a specific implementation of the OPC UA protocol under a dual license: GPL and proprietary: [UA.Net Standard](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard) and build on top of the .NET Framework. It supports the client and server side of OPC UA. You can use it to develop your own OPC UA server or Client.

There are various other commercial and open source OPC UA implementations available. A list of open source OPC UA Implementations can be found here: [List of Open Source OPC UA Implementations](https://github.com/open62541/open62541/wiki/List-of-Open-Source-OPC-UA-Implementations)